# Firebase Notifications Events with FCM

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

there are some events that are logged on Firebase Analytics when you send an notification through the Firebase Notifications on Console (notification_receive, notification_dismiss, notification_foreground, notification_open).

I would like to know if it is possible to log those same events sending the Push Notification through the API (Firebase Cloud Messaging - FCM).

Comment: Did you consider calling the corresponding Firebase Analytics event from your own code? The types in this list look similar enough to make that worth a shot: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event Or are you looking for the events to show up in the Notifications charts (in which case I think there is no public API for that).

Comment: Currently there is no way to track notification events sent via the API, you can as Frank suggests do the tracking yourself through Firebase Analytics which is what is done automatically for you when you use the console.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you elaborate more on the preferred way to do this?  When attempting to use the event names notification_dismiss, notification_foreground, notification_open, or notification_receive, Firebase logs "E/FA: Name is reserved. Type, name: event, notification_receive" and appears to drop it never resulting in a firebase analytics event.